# What component is this? [old monitor]

Tags: identification, components

Anyone knows what component is this? Found scavenging an old monitor.

[image: Big component]

Comment: It's a flyback transformer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_transformer it generates several low and high voltages that are needed in the TV.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie oh, searching the pinout it reminds me of [Electroboom's transformer](https://youtu.be/yeadK4cs_Bs?t=461)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a high voltage transformer, used for electrons post acceleration.

Comment: These are often called "flyback" transformers when used in CRT-based devices.